# Invalid data found when processing input from rtsp stream

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp

im trying to playe rtsp stream with ffplay by this command:

```
ffplay -i rtsp://HOST:1235/qc/Ks3Al3nVHPOt5F -fflags nobuffer -flags low_delay -an -framedrop
```

or

```
ffplay -i rtsp://HOST:1235/qc/Ks3Al3nVHPOt5F
```

But i got an error

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\QuadroCam\ffmpeg>ffplay rtsp://HOST:1235/qc/
Ks3Al3nVHPOt5F
ffplay version 4.1 Copyright (c) 2003-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20181017
  configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3
 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libas
s --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenco
re-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enab
le-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libt
wolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --e
nable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --en
able-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable
-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --
enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --e
nable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
rtsp://HOST:1235/qc/Ks3Al3nVHPOt5F: Invalid data found when processing inpu
t
    nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
```

Maybe need some extra arg for this command or something. Any help please?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to open the same input with vlc and/or ffprobe?

ffprobe will detect stream and show more info.
vlc also can confirm a valid rtsp stream, however it happened to me once vlc opened a stream and ffplay not with an rtsp from a dvr